# How to display other value in database in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have a dropdown from database when I choose an option, I want to display the other data related to the option I choose. How can I achieve that ? Is javascript / jquery can do that ? if so, how ?

[image: Interface]

Below are my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Dropdown value from database</h1>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

  <form action="dropdownfromdb" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <select name="pet">
          <option>Choose Name</option>
          @foreach($memberlist as $member)
            <option value="{{$member->id}}">{{$member->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select><br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <label>His age is: </label><input type="number" name="age" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $memberlist = Member::select('id','name')->get();
        return view('basic.dropdownfromdb',compact('memberlist'));
    }
```

Comment: yes, you will need js, but you first have to get $memberlist more than just id and name. if you want age, then add 'age' in Member::select()

Comment: Yup I already select the age, but how to do the javascript ?

Comment: you pass your $memberlist to js in json, then write an event that triggers when the dropdown is selected, that reads the currently selected id and select the member from id and put the age of that member  in textbox.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but can u show me ? I absolutely no experience in Javascript and trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value 'age' from database and change the controller is as below,

```
public function index()
    {
        $memberlist = Member::select('id','name', 'age')->get();
        return view('basic.dropdownfromdb',compact('memberlist'));
    }
```

Within the event `change` use the following to get the current selected option:

```
var nowAge = $(this).children(':selected').data('age');
```

The following code snippet just prints the selected value and set the `nowAge` to the next `input` field using `$(this).next('input').focus().val(nowAge);`.

Add following jQuery logic with that value.

```
$(".pet-select").change(function () {
    var nowAge = $(this).children(':selected').data('age');
    console.log(nowAge);
    
    $("#age-value").val(nowAge);  
});
```

So your final HTML code segment should be below,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Dropdown value from database</h1>
    <br><br><br>
  </div>

  <form action="dropdownfromdb" method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <select class="pet-select" name="pet">
          <option>Choose Name</option>
          @foreach($memberlist as $member)
            <option value="{{$member->id}}" data-age="{{$member->age}}">{{$member->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select><br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <label>His age is: </label><input type="number" id="age-value" name="age" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope it will be solve your issue.

I have create a complete HTML source code for this issue,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Dropdown value from database</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Dropdown value from database</h1>
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    
    <form action="dropdownfromdb" method="post">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="pet-select" name="pet">
            <option>Choose Name</option>
            <option value="ahmad" data-age="21">Ahmad</option>
            <option value="abu" data-age="27">Abu</option>
            <option value="ali" data-age="21">Ali</option>                        
            </select><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <label>His age is: </label><input type="number" id="age-value" name="age" value="">
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pet-select").change(function () {
    var nowAge = $(this).children(':selected').data('age');
    console.log(nowAge);
    
    $("#age-value").val(nowAge);    
});
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You, but it still not get display any input for age

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope now it will be fine...:)

Comment: Great. With some changes that I made to your answer solve my problem. Thank You very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

try like this one:

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
          <h1>Dropdown value from database</h1>
          <br><br><br>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
                <select name="pet" id="pet">
                      <option>Choose Name</option>
                      @foreach($memberlist as $member)
                           <option value="{{$member->id}}">{{$member->name}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                </select><br><br>
         </div>
     <div class="col-10">
    <label>His age is: </label><input type="number" name="age" value="" id="age">
  </div>
</div>
```

**your script:-**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
        // get id when pet change
        $("#pet").change(function () {
            var id= $(this).val();
           
            $.ajax({
                method:"get",
                url: url: "{{ route('ajax.request') }}",
                 data: {_token:_token, id:id}, 
                success:function (data) {

                     $('#pet').val(data);
                },
                error:function () {

                }
            })

        });
    });

</script>
```

**your route:-**

```
Route::get('ajax/request', [UserController::getAge, 'ajaxRequest'])->name('ajax.request');
```

**your controller method:-**

```
public function getUserAge(Request $request){
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $age = DB::table('your table name')->select('user age column name')->where('user age column name',$id)->first();
    return response->($age->column name);
}
```